# php.ini mysqli.allow_persistent won't turn off even after php restart

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, ini, persistent

What I did:

1. I edited php.ini to include `mysqli.allow_persistent = Off`
2. restarted php
3. php_info -->> shows `mysqli.allow_persistent = On`

I even tried:

1. `ini_set('mysqli.allow_persistent', "Off");`
2. but php_info -->> still shows mysqli.allow_persistent = On

Why and how to fix this?

Comment: If on a shared host, it could be an enforced rule at that level. Shared hosts often enforce certain rules that cannot be overridden because they would be detrimental to other customers sharing server resources. Also, what kind of server? Apache? IIS? I assume that's what you're restarting since PHP itself can't really be "restarted" per se.

Comment: It's on my own linux, latest WHM, latest PHP, MariaDB

Comment: According to the official documentation, `mysqli.allow_persistent` takes an integer value, 0 being off and 1 being on. The older `mysql.allow_persistent` (without the i) used an On/Off toggle. That being said, I've used On/Off for mysqli as well and it worked, although maybe newer versions of PHP are more restrictive. I'd give `mysqli.allow_persistent = 0` a try.

Comment: ;) thanks it worked with 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli.allow_persistent` actually expects an integer value, the default being `1` according to the documentation. This can be a bit confusing since `mysql.allow_persistent` (without the i) uses an On/Off toggle, and On/Off also works for `mysqli` in some older versions of PHP.

To disable it, use this in your php.ini:

`mysqli.allow_persistent = 0`